# replace a^2 and b^2 with a different rule to ab

Tags: replacement

I have an expression and need to replace all instances of $x^2$ with $a$, all instances of $y^2$ with $b$ and all instances of $xy$ with $0$, but I only know how to replace $x$ or $y$ individually. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: `expr/.{x^2->a,y^2->b,x y->0}`?

Comment: Hmm, yes that works. I had it in my head that you could only replace single variables, not expressions. Thanks!